# F test for regressions with a small N with robust standard errors

Tags: stata, robust, f-test

I have a binary dummy with only a very small number of values for this dummy set to "1" (say 7 out of 120).  When I run the regression the F-test using robust standard errors, the f-test does not show in Stata.  I need to report why this happens. If I remove the robust option, the f-test shows.

Comment: No this is not the same question and there's no answer in that question you suggest. Specifically, here the question is that the F-test does not show only when the values of the dummy set to 1 are small.

Comment: Although you ask the question differently and circumstances may be a little different, it concerns *identical* behavior by your software.  There's no need to have two threads open for discussing this: that's why we identify duplicates and create links between them (which is what "closing") does.